# Como hacer que mis datos se mantengan guardados en mi tabla html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, datatables

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación, en la cual tengo un par de textbox como input, el objetivo es que, el usuario escriba un número de orden en el input y hacer una consulta a la base de datos para sacar información de ese número de orden y al final colocar esa información en una tabla. En seguido muestro una pantalla de la web:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema que tengo es que, en el contenedor "search by", cuando el usuario busca la información por orden aparece un el input, coloca el nombre de orden y esta va y busca a la BD, después mediante ajax hago la escritura en la tabla.. el problema viene cuando quiero hacer un sort con los eventos de data table, al hacer clic a cualquiera de ellos los datos que coloque en mi tabla desaparecen, por ejemplo:

[image: Aqui tengo mis datos en la tabla sin hacer clic a cualquier evento]

Aquí tengo el dato en mi tabla al enviarlo mediante un boton con submit y ajax, cuando doy clic en el evento desaparecen mis datos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien sabe como puedo solucionar esto?, es decir, que cuando de clic en cualquier evento, mis datos esten guardado y no se pierdan.

Dejo el código html:

**Formulario de los inputs**

```
  <!-- Order or MFGN form begin-->
        <p class="ibm-margin-top-2" id="order">
          <label for="order-mfgn" class="" id="Enter"> Enter order</label>
          <span class="ibm-center-block">
            <input type="text" id="order-value"> <button class="ibm-btn-pri ibm-btn-blue-50" id="submit-order" type="submit" name="order">Submit</button>
          </span>
        </p>
        <p class="ibm-margin-top-2" id="mfgn">
          <label for="mfgn-value" class="" id="Enter"> Enter mfgn </label>
          <span class="ibm-center-block">
            <input type="text" id="mfgn-value" > <button class="ibm-btn-pri ibm-btn-blue-50" id="submit-mfgn" type="submit">Submit</button>
          </span>
        </p>
      </form>
      <!-- Enter the order MFGN end -->
```

**contenedor de la tabla (jinja2)**

```
  <div class="ibm-col-12-8 ibm-margin-top-3">
    <!-- table container begin-->

    {% block table %} {% endblock %}
  </div>
```

**Javascript para obtener los datos y enviarlos a la tabla**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#submit-order').click(function(evt) {
evt.preventDefault();

var order = $('#order-value').val();
data = {
  order: order
}
console.log(data);


$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/",
  data:data,
  success: function(response) {
    // console.log('The data is send successfully' + response.order);
    $('#data').html(
      "<tr>"+
      "<td>"+ response.order+"</td>"+
      "<td>"+ response.Mfgn+"</td>"+
      "<td>"+response.Test+"</td>"+
      "<td>"+response.Date+"</td>"+
      "<td>"+ response.Expected+"</td>"+
      "</tr>"
    )
    $('#Enter').value = "";

  }
    });
});

 // $('#submit-mfgn').click(function() {
//   // alert('clic')
//   console.log('clic');
 });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema son los botones submit,

no se que funciones estés utilizando, pero los submit siempre envían una petición al servidor que trae una nueva forma limpia.

tienes dos opciones :

1.- ver de que manera puedes cambiar esos submit a que sean botones normales con ajax
2.- agregar el metodo "get" a tus submit para que todos los valores de tu form sean reenviados en la URL y de ahi puedas leerlos para colocarlos con javascript nuevamente en sus respectivos controles

ejemplo:

```
  <button class="ibm-btn-pri ibm-btn-blue-50" id="submit-mfgn" type="submit" method="get">Submit</button>
```